# adMob integration with BlackBerry z10

Tags: admob, blackberry-10, ads

I'm creating a mobile application that will use adMob for advertising service in BlackBerry z10. Is there any guides for the integration in adMob for BlackBerry z10?
I really need help on this one. Thank you very much.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_